# Density matrix of a beam of spin -1/2 particles after it has passed through a Stern-Gerlach device

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, density-operator

I'm trying to find the density matrix $\rho_\gamma$ of a beam described by the density matrix $\rho_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{3}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$, after it has passed through the following Stern-Gerlach device:

[image]

I'm not sure if $\rho_\gamma$ is just $\rho_\gamma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, since the $|\downarrow⟩$-state is blocked, if it's $\rho_\gamma = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, because the $|\uparrow⟩$-state only had a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ to begin with or if it's something else entirely.
I've been also thinking about using $\rho_\gamma = p_\uparrow |\uparrow⟩ ⟨\uparrow|$, but I don't know if $p_\uparrow$ is 1 or $\frac{1}{4}$.
So my question is what method is best suited for these kind of problems and maybe for more complicated ones and what's wrong with my attempts, because they all kind of make sense to me, but they all feel wrong.

Comment: as written, your $\rho_0$ is a state, not a density operator.  The trace (however it may be defined for your $\rho_0$) is not $1$ so it is not a valid density operator.  As a state it is not normalized either.

Comment: Forgot to check the density matrix after I typed it in. Should be fine now, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the measurement update rule in quantum mechanics. The S-G device essentially performs a "measurement" on the quantum state: if the beam emerges, it means the result of the measurement was indeed $\uparrow$, so the state must be $|\uparrow\rangle\langle \uparrow|$. This result occurs with probability $p_\uparrow$; the rest of the probability is that the beam does not emerge.

You can do this update rule by acting with the projector $P_\uparrow=|\uparrow\rangle\langle \uparrow|$ on your state from both sides *and then normalizing*,
$$\rho\to \frac{P_\uparrow \rho P_\uparrow}{\rm{Tr}(P_\uparrow \rho P_\uparrow)}.$$ Or... all of your intuition is correct, the final state must be normalized, and it is only the probability of finding that final state that may change with the initial state.